# How to order by timestamp and group based on score

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

How to order by timestamp and group based on score

1. Entities starting with a prefix (say a1 are similar), but we need to
   pickup the one with the highest score, in this case `a1-1`
2. For a2 it should pickup `a2-1`, since it has a score of 0.6
3. For a3, it should be `a3-0`
4. For a4, it should be `a4-1`, since its recent
5. Assume time is mentioned based on creation time ascending (i.e t1, t2 ...)

`entities table` contains the following

```
1. a1-0, x0, 0.8, t1
2. a2-0, x1, 0.5, t2
3. a2-1, x2, 0.6, t3
4. a3-0, x3, 0.8, t4
5. a2-2, x4, 0.7, t5
6. a1-1, x5, 0.9, t6
7. a4-0, x6, 0.6, t7
8. a4-1, x7, 0.6, t8
9. a1-2, x8, 0.85, t9
```

This is the output I expect, what SQL query should I use

1. a4-1
2. a3-0
3. a2-1
4. a1-1

Answer (score 0):

[From the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

> `SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] )` keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The `DISTINCT ON` expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for `ORDER BY` (see above). Note that the “first row” of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first.

You can combine that with [string functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) to establish sets based on the prefix. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/d2XfeKUf):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON( (string_to_array(code,'-'))[1] )
       code
FROM entities
ORDER BY (string_to_array(code,'-'))[1] DESC, 
         score         DESC, 
         creation_time DESC;
```

| code |
| --- |
| a4-1 |
| a3-0 |
| a2-2 *(this had score of 0.7, which is more than a2-1's 0.6)* |
| a1-1 |

- `(string_to_array(code,'-'))` cuts up the code at each `-` producing an array, then `[1]` takes its first element, which will be the prefix.
- [`ORDER BY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) dictates that the prefix is primarily responsible for the position. You wanted highest prefix first so you need DESCending order. `DISTINCT ON` will discard all but one record for each prefix.
- Out of each set of records sharing a prefix, you wanted the top score, hence the second `ORDER BY` expression is `score DESC`.
- The latest timestamp will have the highest value, so to pick `a4-1` over `a4-0` based on the more recent creation time, you need `creation_time DESC`.

---

It's good to [normalise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) your structure. You're holding multiple pieces of information as a single `code`, which forces you to use string functions in order to separate them and process individually:

- If that's how you're receiving the data, you can add [generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-GENERATED-STORED) to parse the code automatically or set up a [view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) on top of the table.
- If you have control over the construction of these records, save each underlying piece of information into a separate column. Using `a2-0` as an example, put the primary group identifier `a` into one column, secondary `2` into another, order number `0` into another. You might prefer to just split into prefix and suffix, but the extra granularity might be worth it if you consider that text sorts `a800` ahead, as a lower value than `a9` ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/A-ILXhPM)).

Answer (score -1):

User Postgresql's brilliant `distinct on` with custom order.

```sql
select distinct on (split_part(ent_id, '-', 1)) ent_id
from the_table
order by (split_part(ent_id, '-', 1)), score desc, ts;
```

| ent_id |
| --- |
| a1-1 |
| a2-2 |
| a3-0 |
| a4-0 |

Pls. note that 'a2-2' has higher score than 'a2-1'.
Live demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3GTDThp1t4RTseTZFmHkDi/0)

Comment: Yes, except that more "recent" should translate to `ts DESC`, resulting in `a4-1`.

Comment: @ErinBrandstetter Oh sure, thanks